# How to make a dynamic route in Gatsby at the beginning of the URL

Tags: gatsby

Can I make dynamic routes on GatsbyJs from the beginning of the URL? Some examples that I find are always static/:dynamic, can I make it like this:

```
<Route path: "/:category/read/:slug_post"/>
```

which "category" will always change.

Currently I use custom routes like this on my gatsby-node.js. Where the bases are "read" and it's static.

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path.match(/^\/read/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/read/*"
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

Now I don't use GraphQL, and in the "pages" folder I create a file called "read.js" and it contains code like this:

```
import { Router as MyRouter } from "@reach/router"

<MyRouter>
  <Read path="/read/:category_slug/:post_id/:post_slug" />
</MyRouter>
```

Here I rather do not follow the best practice it seems.

Comment: Do you mean in your page/post creation?

Comment: @FerranBuireu This is an example https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5081656/lengkap-ini-alasan-edhy-prabowo-ngotot-buka-ekspor-benih-lobster

Can we make the "berita-ekonomi-bisnis" dynamic when we open another articles. Or do we have to make it for each category? like this :

<Route path: "/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/:id/:slug" />

and for each category we need to create a file in the "pages" folder

or I can use it like this:

<Route path: "/:category/:id/:slug />

Comment: Then, each `post` will belong to a certain `category` isn't it? In that case, you'll need to query everything in your `gatsby-node.js`. Share some of your code to see what you've tried and seen how we can help to improve the code.

Comment: I currently use custom routes like this on my gatsby-node.js, where the bases are "read" and it's static.

exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path.match(/^\/read/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/read/*"
    createPage(page)
  }
}

Comment: Not as a comment, editing n your question, please.

Comment: Sure, I will change the question to include my script snippet

Comment: Would you mind including your GraphQL query to show how you get `category` as well as `posts`?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to redo your project's logic. Check:  https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/

Comment: Okay, thank you. Looks like I have to read a lot of documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, but it seems to me that you do not need dynamic routing. If you just create each page with its final URL according to the pattern you need (e.g. `/read/<category_slug>/<id>/<post_slug>`) you should be all set and you wouldn't need to define a router.

See the [Gatsby blog starter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/master/gatsby-node.js); in it, pages are created with `path: post.node.fields.slug` but there is nothing preventing you from creating more complicated paths.